# Layout in a Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a design that will be look like this image [`Image Link`](http://s2.postimg.org/4fxhrwik9/itin_new1.png).I am not able design this layout.Please help me to create this layout .this is what i tried to create this but unfortunately i am not getting this how i will set this image and text.Please help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ItinearyPage" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_ScrollView_Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_Inside_ScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itin_Section_First"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travel_Itenary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/tarvelItinaryText"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itin_Section_Second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itin_Section_First"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itin_Section_First"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_demo" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to get this it's my first assignment.I am stucked in this from last 2 days .I read my many tutorials and website but still i am not able to get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Updated my answer** 

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItinearyPage" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ScrollView_Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itin_Section_First"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/travel_Itenary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tarvelItinaryText"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Travel Consultant :"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itin_Section_Second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_demo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/firstfreeText"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/second_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/secondfreeText"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/third_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/thirdfreeText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fourth_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fourthfreeText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fifth_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fifthfreeText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sixth_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sixthfreeText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seventh_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/seventhfreeText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eight_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/eightthfreeText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ninth_free_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ninethfreeText" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this one and modify as per your requirement
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ItinearyPage" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ScrollView_Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itin_Section_First"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travel_Itenary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itin_Section_Second"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_demo"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview3"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview4"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview5"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview3"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview4"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview5"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview3"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview4"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="textview5"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this is perfect what i want to get but i am not able to set the text side by side as in the image please help i will be thank full to you \

Comment: six word are there in each line like text,text text and the text i am not able to set this

Comment: as in the image i have posted the text will be like that

Comment: are you posting something for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_ScrollView_Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_Inside_ScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travel_Itenary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="tarvelItinaryText"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/homescreen_logo" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_Inside_ScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travel_Itenary"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="tarvelItinaryText tarvelItinaryText tarvelItinaryText"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/homescreen_logo" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: will you please help to desing the complete layout i am in android from last 7 days please help me.see the image i want to create the UI some thing like that

Comment: @pooja please check this image link: `http://s5.postimg.org/kewyie9pj/untitled.png`    and tell me .is it proper output or not what you want?

Comment: pooja please post your real image what you want.imageview show images not text.then i will understand what you want?have you check my image?

Comment: yup there will be image at place of imageview

Comment: please put some real image then i have some idea what you want.

Comment: @PoojaDubey see i have updated my answer it will help you for sure

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your LinearLayout orientation 
like

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itin_Section_First"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the attached snapshot and check if it solves the purpose. I have made your required UI using TableView. Please check if it solves the purpose.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/itin_Section_First"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/travel_Itenary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your Text"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".9" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.1" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Text :"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Your Text"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]